# Screen-like interface in HTML

Tags: html, silverlight

I have some 10 odd Silverlight based components. I wanted to create a screen like interface in HTML, each screen holding some number of components and the user can easily navigate between the screens and use the components.

Can anyone suggest me some way in which I could easily implement such an interface?

Thank You.

Comment: can you tell more about this 'screen like interface in HTML' ?

Comment: If I can make it a bit clear. Lets consider an Android hoem screen the way it has some x screens, each screen having different widgets/apps, I want to create a HTML page with such screens (I dont wish to give each screen a different URL), I want it to have a smooth fast transition between screens. I want some suggestions of implementing this in some easy manner. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your question you need [Navigation Framework](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx).
With it you can have any number of pages(screens in your case) and navigate between them.
You also can do that kind of things using behavios. Very good video is avaliable at silverlight.tv : [Creating Rich Interactions Using Blend 4: Transition Effects, Fluid Layout, and Layout States](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Creating-Rich-Interactions-Using-Blend-4-Transition-Effects-Fluid-Layout-and-Layout-States-Silverlig)